# How to send email when using B2C Custom Policies to call Azure Function?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c

When a user is created or logs in, a function is called. That function will then trigger a **Logic App**. The logic app needs to send email to the newly added user.

Here's the model that capture input coming from B2C.

```
public class InputClaimsDto
{
    public string oid { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
}
```

All the fields are being populated except **email**.

Here's the entire **Technical Profile**.

```
<!-- Custom Restful service -->
    <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-API-SignUp">
      <InputClaims>            
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectid" PartnerClaimType="oid" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="firstName" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="lastName" />

        <!--I'm trying to return the email-->
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" PartnerClaimType="email" />

      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
         //...
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

To return the email, I've tried `email`, `signInNames.emailAddress`, `otherMails`, but it's not working.

How to return email or any other data.

Thanks for helping.

## EDIT

In the TrustFrameworkBse.xml, **email** is define as `Email address that can be used to contact you.`

```
<ClaimType Id="email">
    <DisplayName>Email Address</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="email" />
    </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
    <UserHelpText>Email address that can be used to contact you.</UserHelpText>
    <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
    <Restriction>
      <Pattern RegularExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&amp;'^_`{}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$" HelpText="Please enter a valid email address." />
    </Restriction>
  </ClaimType>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing link here is, we do not know if `email` is a populated claim by the time we get to your REST API call. The code snippet is not sufficient to tell.

Referencing the AAD B2C Starter Pack, at Sign In the email is captured in a claim called `signInName`. At Sign Up, the email is captured in a claim called `email`.

To normalise this situtation, call your REST API technical profile after the `AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId` step. In the `AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId`, add an output claim as follows:

```xml
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" />
```

This will mean, regardless of Sign In or Sign Up, we will read the directory attribute `signInNames.emailAddress`, and insert its value into a claim called `email`.

Now when you call your REST API, `email` will have a value, always. Your REST API should use the following:

```xml
<InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email"/>
```

Comment: `AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId` is only in the `TrustFrameworkBase.xml`.  My understanding is that we shouldn't touch the that file.

Comment: Btw, I'm using `<InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="email" />` as you suggested, and it's working.

Comment: Probably that won’t work at sign up, since signInName doesn’t exist. You can override AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId in extensions rather than changing it directly in the base file. That is the full solution.